# persistentstorecoordinator coredata error:NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 522

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am working with ios project in which I delete database at time of logout but when I try to relogin with another user I get error  as following:

> NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 522

My code on logout is as following:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self contentStorageDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"*****.sqlite"];
    [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
    self.managedObjectContext = nil;
    self.managedObjectModel = nil;
    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
    [self getManagedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Why you are deleting .sqlite file as this is not the way to clean all data by deleting .sql file for that you need to write delete query to delete old user data while logout from app.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the database when logout ?. Maybe your trying to delete all previous logged in user data. You must read a little more about CoreData. You can nil the context, but persistence store coordinator should not be touched because have a reference to the model working with.

how can you getManagedObjectContext, when the store is assigned to nil

take a look at your model, your entity´s relations have something called Delete Rules, could be **Deny, Nullify, Cascade and No Action.**

from apple :

> A relationship's delete rule specifies what should happen if an
>   attempt is made to delete the source object.

so what you should try is delete all user data after logout.

if you want to debug every movement on the underlying engine of CoreData put this con your Run scheme, on the arguments passed on launch

**-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1**